# View a pdf with Webview Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin, webview

I would like to use a webview to view a pdf but something must be missing.

Custom Webview code:

```
class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Uri), typeof(string), typeof(CustomWebView), default(string));

    public string Uri { 
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

CustomWebViewRenderer code:

```
class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    public CustomWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var customWebView = Element as CustomWebView;
            Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", string.Format("file:///android_asset/Content/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(customWebView.Uri))));
        }
    }
}
```

xaml code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button HeightRequest="100" 
            WidthRequest="200"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            Clicked="Button_Clicked" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <!--<local:CustomWebView Grid.Row="1" Uri="test.pdf" x:Name="PdfViewer"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>-->
    <local:CustomWebView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PdfViewer"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

mainpage.xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PdfViewer.Uri = "test.pdf";
}
```

If I set uri from xaml the pdf is displayed but if I set it from the code behind it doesn't work.

How can I set the pdf from the code behind? Using debugging when I set the pdf from the code behind does not occur CustomWebViewRenderer.OnElementChanged and therefore does not update, how can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to display local pdf in the webview? If so, android webview cannot display local pdf like iOS, You can try to use custom renderer to achieve it like this thread:https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/xamarin-forms/Controls/display-pdf

Comment: Can you update a demo about your issue? Because I can not reproduce this issue.